# josso newbie setup problems - can't use tomcat's manager page

Tags: java, single-sign-on, tomcat6, josso

I'm trying to setup josso on an apache tomcat server running on windows.

I've installed Apache Tomcat/6.0.26 fro zip file to c:\tomcat

then installed josso following the documentation at

http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Quick+Start

started tomcat with c:\tomcat\bin\startup.bat, and noticed the following warnings

> ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Realm} Setting property '
>   debug' to '1' did not find a matching property.
>   21/03/2010 15:55:03 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>   ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Valve} Setting prope
>   rty 'appName' to 'josso' did not find a matching property.
>   ...
>
> ADVERTENCIA: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and j
>   avax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
>   ...
>
> ADVERTENCIA: Bean with key 'josso:type=SSOAuditManager' has been registered as a
>   n MBean but has no exposed attributes or operations
>   ...

but then everything seems to work fine, the problem is I can no longer access http://localhost:8080/manager/html using user tomcat /tomcat, as configured in \conf\tomcat-users.xml (before installing josso it worked)

I tried with tomcat/tomcatpwd as defined in \lib\josso-credentials.xml and even added tomcat  and the manager role to \lib\josso-users.xml, with no luck...

Is anybody having the same problem? how can I access tomcat's manager page?

Thanks a lot

saludos

sas

This is my config:

```
C:\tomcat\bin>catalina version
Using CATALINA_BASE: "C:\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME: "C:\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME: "c:\java"
Using CLASSPATH: "C:\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar"
Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Server built: March 9 2010 1805
Server number: 6.0.26.0
OS Name: Windows XP
OS Version: 5.1
Architecture: x86
JVM Version: 1.5.0_22-b03
JVM Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc
```

ps: moreover, when shutting down, I get a couple of error like this

> GRAVE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [JOSSOAssertionM
>   onitor] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   21/03/2010 15:57:06 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferences
>   Threads

and then tomcat's shutdown freezes at

> 21/03/2010 15:57:07 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol destroy
>   INFO: Parando Coyote AJP/1.3 en ajp-8009

ps: sorry for this lengthy question...

Comment: I get this warn:

ADVERTENCIA: Bean with key 'josso:type=SSOAuditManager' has been registered as a n MBean but has no exposed attributes or operations ...


How did you fix it?? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may helps you to correct the problem (can't access manager page).

1:In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml file remove the following code if present
$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

2:For each non-jossified application add a  with  configuration in $CATALINA_BASE/conf//

(i.e. In Catalina/localhost set the Tomcat Manager web application as non-jossified)
$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/server/webapps/manager" privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="true" antiJARLocking="true">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Jossify+your+Application+for+Tomcat+-+Quick+Start